# Reducing a N-Sum to a Two Sum

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I've recently came across a cool algorithm to reduce any problem of the sort "Find n numbers in an array that sum to a target" to a Two Sum problem. However, I am having a hard time understanding one line of the code.

```
def findNsum(nums, target, N, result, results):
    if len(nums) < N or N < 2 or target < nums[0]*N or target > nums[-1]*N:  # early termination
        return
    if N == 2: # two pointers solve sorted 2-sum problem
        l,r = 0,len(nums)-1
        while l < r:
            s = nums[l] + nums[r]
            if s == target:
                results.append(result + [nums[l], nums[r]])
                l += 1
                while l < r and nums[l] == nums[l-1]:
                    l += 1
            elif s < target:
                l += 1
            else:
                r -= 1
    else: # recursively reduce N
        for i in range(len(nums)-N+1):
            if i == 0 or (i > 0 and nums[i-1] != nums[i]):
                findNsum(nums[i+1:], target-nums[i], N-1, result+[nums[i]], results)

results = []
findNsum(sorted(nums), 0, 3, [], results)
return results
```

The condition:

```
if i == 0 or (i > 0 and nums[i-1] != nums[i]):
```

Does not make sense to me. Why do I have to check `if nums[i-1] != nums[i]`? If I try it out with, say, with `nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 2, -1, -4]`, I get `[[-4, 2, 2], [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]` with the condition. If I take it out I get `[[-4, 2, 2], [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]]`. Can any one make sense of this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The condition `nums[i-1] != nums[i]` is to avoid creating duplicate solutions when picking the first element, which can see in your output in the second example. This problem wants to find all unique solutions, not all possible solutions, hence we want to drop the second `[-1,0,1]`